# Using decltype with member function pointers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, templates, c++11

I have some trouble using `decltype` for member function pointers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A
{
    void func1() {}
    typedef decltype(&A::func1) type;
};

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    typedef decltype(&A::func1) type;

    //Case 1
    std::wcout
        << std::boolalpha
        << std::is_member_function_pointer<type>::value
        << std::endl;

    //Case 2
    std::wcout
        << std::boolalpha
        << std::is_member_function_pointer<A::type>::value
        << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Case 1 prints `true` as expected, but Case 2 prints `false`.

Is `decltype` stripping away the "member" property of a type? If so, why?

Also, is there a way to prevent this behavior? I need to get the type of a member function regardless of where I use `decltype`.

Please help.

**EDIT:**

[Reported to Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/678194/decltype-strips-member-property-from-member-function-pointers)

Comment: Seems like another limitation with `decltype` in the current MSVC implementation...

Comment: Just checked with gcc 4.7, it outputs `true` for both cases.

Comment: @Xeo @Vitus Thanks. Microsoft ruins everything...

Comment: @Nubcase: it is not necessary to put garbage on Microsoft in every chance, just on principle. EG. Bjarne Stroustrup said that MS compiler is the best out there... :)

Comment: clang + libc++ prints out `true` for both cases too.

Comment: gcc 4.7 is much newer than VC2010, I'm assuming the clang implementation @Howard tested is too.  Report this on MS Connect and it should hopefully be fixed in the next compiler revision.

Comment: @relaxxx I was just kidding ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of formality (having an answer to the question), this appears to be a bug in VC2010's compiler. File a bug report so that Microsoft can fix it in the next version.