# Using decltype with virtual member function pointers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++11

Is it legal to use `decltype` with virtual member function pointers?

The following generates an internal error (C1001) with VS2012.

```
struct C
{
    virtual void Foo() {}

    typedef decltype(&C::Foo) type;   //pointer
}
```

But this compiles fine:

```
struct C
{
    virtual void Foo() {}

    typedef decltype(C::Foo) type;   //not pointer
}
```

Is it a bug?

Comment: It it was "illegal" it would generate an error message, not an internal error. You obviously found a bug in the compiler.

Comment: @AndreyT: +1, I would add that: *even if it was illegal it should not cause an internal error*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSVC has multiple known issues with `decltype` to member function pointers; see also [Using decltype with member function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557565/using-decltype-with-member-function-pointers)

This is legal syntax; g++ is perfectly happy with it (http://ideone.com/sTZi6).  There is nothing in the standard to restrict the operation of `decltype` on member functions.